# Django seems to escape HTML characters (but is not supposed to)

Tags: python, django, localization, translation

After upgrading Django from 1.8 to 1.9.8 (and also upgrading a bunch of modules in the process), I've got an issue with my translations inside templates.

With the `Foobar` key associated with the `foo<br>bar` string, the code:

```
<p>{% i18n 'Foobar' %}</p>
```

was working great before the upgrade, displaying:

```
foo
bar
```

But now, it displays:

```
foo<br>bar
```

Any idea?

Comment: try with ```{% autoescape on %} {% endautoescape %}```. But depending on you case, sending html is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. So I guess the default value for `autoescape` changed between v1.8 and v1.9.8...

Comment: So, is there a way to set `autoescape` to `false` by default, instead of adding `{% autoescape off %}` in all my templates?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html maybe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I cannot really remove the HTML tags from my strings (in fact, it's BBCode which is transformed to HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to Bestasttung's comment, I solved my problem with this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
<p>{% i18n 'Foobar' %}</p>
{% endautoescape %}
```

But that wasn't very satisfying since I had multiple templates to update.
So, I simply changed my `i18n` method from:

```
def i18n(context, key):
    ...
    return s
```

to:

```
def i18n(context, key):
    ...
    return mark_safe(s)
```

I hope that will help someone facing the same issue.